# How to view console.log in tizen web app after app runs

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

I am trying to develop a Gear S2 app which uses the Samsung accessory protocol to communicate with an Android app.  The issue is that the Gear S2 does not have a USB connection, debug connection is done over wifi.  However, when the Gear S2 bluetooth connects to the phone, it disables wifi, so I lose debug connection while the app is running.  Afterwards I run "sdb dlog" but I don't see any of the console.log() messages in that log.

Is there a way to run the app and then see the console.log() messages afterwards?  From another site I tried "sdb dlog ConsoleMessage:V" but that didn't work..

Comment: Gear S2 does have option of USB connection.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  Gear S2 only has wireless charging and no USB connection. (Not to be confused with Gear 2 which does have USB connection)

Comment: Aaron - I m nt confused with Gear 2. I use Gear S2 with USB connection. Haven't you got the wire charger?

Comment: No, just the wireless docking charger: http://www.androidcentral.com/sites/androidcentral.com/files/styles/xlarge_wm_brw/public/article_images/2015/09/samsung-gear-s2-charger-face.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work better with actual Firmware.

I'm using a SM-R732 with R732XXU2BOL6 Firmware and is paired via Bluetooth but also WiFi is running in the background and I can connect via SDB without disable BT. 
I know this wasn't working at the beging, but it seems they have changed something with one of the last Firmwares.

Just try to update your Gear S2 and use the latest SDK (2.4 Rev3) and it should work.